# Generic Handler Takes time to load the Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datatable, handler

I am loading a DataTable through a Handler. The handler Calls a class that returns a list and this list is displayed on to the Datatable. It takes loads of time(4-5 minutes) to load that table. But when I run the stored procedure on the server then it executes in less than a second.  Am I doing something wrong?
It's a simple asp.net application with c# and the backend is mssql.

```
 public class StaffCatData
    {
        public int TotalStaff { get; set; }
        public double Percentage { get; set; }
        public int TotalSurvey { get; set; }
        public string StaffCategory { get; set; }

        public static List<StaffCatData> GetStaffCat(int hid)
        {
            List<StaffCatData> list = new List<StaffCatData>();
            Connection Con = new Connection();
            String Connection = Con.Active_Connection();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connection);
            con.Open();
            string query = "StaffCategory";
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param", hid));
                command.CommandTimeout = 600;
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        StaffCatData sd = new StaffCatData();
                        sd.StaffCategory = Convert.ToString(reader["StaffCategory"]) + " " + Convert.ToString(reader["StaffCatTooltip"]);
                        sd.TotalSurvey = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Survey"]);
                        sd.TotalStaff = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Staff"]);
                        sd.Percentage = Convert.ToDouble(reader["Percantage"]);
                        list.Add(sd);
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
                command.Dispose();
                con.Close();
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
```

this is the class the handler calls before loading to the Datatable.

Comment: How you measure that exactly this class taking 5-6 minutes to load data?

Comment: When I run the handler. The page keeps loading for that much long time before the data table is filled.

Comment: It looks good to me. Measure the time between `command.CommandTimeout = 600;` and `reader.Close();`. You can use a [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Loading page include much more actions than just loading data from database. Especially if you "copying" data from one collection to the `DataTable`. Just curios why you need to copy it from nicely strong typed object to the database row?

Comment: There is no `DataTable` in your code.

Comment: Yes. That is the only the output from this handler. If I run this handler separately it takes long time to load data.